# How to plot horizontal y label

Tags: r, plot, label

I tried to plot a horizontal y label using the following code:

```
require(grDevices)

par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(0,3,0,0.5)+0.1, oma=c(3,0,0.5,0)+0.1, 
    mgp=c(2,1,0), cex=tcex)
par(las=1)
#pl-d001
plot(1, type="n", yaxt='n', xaxt='n', xaxs="i", yaxs="i", xlab="xlabel", 
     ylab=expression("axis "*italic(r[infinity])), xlim=c(0, 0.4), ylim=c(0, 1))
```

But, I only get a normal (vertical) Y label. What is wrong here?

[image]

Comment: `las` is for the tick labels, you want to use `mtext`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @rawr said in the comments, your best chance is with `mtext`:

```
plot(1, type="n", yaxt='n', xaxt='n', xaxs="i", yaxs="i", 
     xlab="xlabel", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 0.4), ylim=c(0, 1))
mtext(expression("axis "*italic(r[infinity])),side=2,las=1,line=1)
```

The reason why you can't do that directly from `plot` is that, internally, `plot` uses `title` to draw those labels and `title` (for some reason)  doesn't take `las` or `srt` as arguments.